# Only getting last letter of string

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am using NgRX 6 with Angular 6.

I have an effect that calls a service, that service returns a string.

For some reason I am only getting the last letter of the string.

This is my effect

```
  @Effect()
  identityRedirect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN),
    switchMap(() =>
      forkJoin(this.discoverService.getServiceUrl('{api:identity}'), this.discoverService.getServiceUrl('{site:self}'))
    ),
    mergeMap(([x, y]: [string, string]) => {
      console.log(x);
      console.log(y);
      return of({ type: REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: 'foo' });
    })
  );
```

I thought that a `forkJoin` would help but all I seem to get in my console log is the final letter

My discovery service looks like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import endpoints from './endpoints';

@Injectable()
export default class DiscoverService {
  constructor() {}

  public getServiceUrl = (service: string) => {
    const { domain, endpoint } = this.splitServiceObject(service);
    return endpoints[domain][endpoint]['uri'];
  }

  private splitServiceObject = (service: string) => {
    const moduleParams = service.split(/{(.*)}/);
    const [domain, endpoint] = moduleParams[1].split(':');
    return { domain, endpoint };
  }
}
```

Comment: You're getting only last letter where?

Comment: When I console log the result in the mergeMap

Answer (score 0):

So I changed my effect to look like this

```
  @Effect()
  identityRedirect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN),
    switchMap(() =>
      combineLatest(
        this.discoverService.getServiceUrl('{api:identity}'),
        this.discoverService.getServiceUrl('{site:self}')
      )
    ),
    mergeMap(([auth, redirect]: [string, string]) => {
      console.log(auth);
      console.log(redirect);
      return of({ type: REDIRECT_TO_LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: 'error' });
    })
  );
```

I also needed to update my service like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import endpoints from './endpoints';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export default class DiscoverService {
  constructor() {}

  public getServiceUrl = (service: string): Observable<string> => {
    return this.splitServiceObject(service).pipe(map(([domain, endpoint]) => endpoints[domain][endpoint]['uri']));
  }

  private splitServiceObject = (service: string): Observable<any> => {
    const moduleParams = service.split(/{(.*)}/);
    // const [domain, endpoint] = moduleParams[1].split(':');
    return of(moduleParams[1].split(':'));
  }
}
```